# Spring Boot executable JAVA_OPTS override with spaces

Tags: java, spring-boot, command-line-arguments, executable-jar

I'm using Spring Boot 1.4.1 to create an executable Unix JAR file (per the instructions [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html)). I'm using a custom .conf file to set the `JAVA_OPTS` value at run-time. This has been working fine with the following contents:

> JAVA_OPTS="-Dspring.profiles.active=prod -Dflyway.validate-on-migrate=false -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/var/myapp/truststore.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit"

I now want to override a parameter that I've got configured in my application.yml file (that's embedded within the JAR). The problem is that the values of this parameter have spaces in them.

I've tried:

> JAVA_OPTS="-Dmy.param=One Two
>   -Dspring.profiles.active=prod -Dflyway.validate-on-migrate=false -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/var/myapp/truststore.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit"

...and...

> JAVA_OPTS="-Dmy.param=One\ Two
>   -Dspring.profiles.active=prod -Dflyway.validate-on-migrate=false -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/var/myapp/truststore.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit"

...and...

> JAVA_OPTS=-Dmy.param=One\ Two
>   -Dspring.profiles.active=prod -Dflyway.validate-on-migrate=false -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/var/myapp/truststore.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit

...and...

> JAVA_OPTS=""-Dmy.param=One\ Two"
>   -Dspring.profiles.active=prod -Dflyway.validate-on-migrate=false -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/var/myapp/truststore.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit"

But I get various error messages like:

> Error: Could not find or load main class Two

...or...

> /var/myapp/myapp.conf line 1: Two: command not found

I've looked inside the code that's embedded in the top of the JAR file and it seems to be:

```
arguments=(-Dsun.misc.URLClassPath.disableJarChecking=true $JAVA_OPTS -jar $jarfile $RUN_ARGS "$@")
```

...but I'm having trouble working out how to translate this into a JAVA_OPTS value that works

Comment: Spaces (and quotes) in arguments particularly in -D arguments are incredibly difficult to get right with bash scripts and in some cases impossible. I recommend putting that config in environment variables or config files.

Comment: Did you try this `JAVA_OPTS=-Dmy.param="One Two" -D..........`

Comment: @LipingHuang From when I set this up originally (without the new parameter) the whole line needs to be quoted, otherwise I get `-Dflyway.validate-on-migrate=false: command not found`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was using an externalised `application.yml` per the instructions [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html). Still not exactly what I wanted, but it'll do for now.

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem and found that escaping the embedded double quotes with backslash did the trick, like this:

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Dmy.param=\"One Two\" -Dspring.profiles.active=prod -Dflyway.validate-on-migrate=false -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/var/myapp/truststore.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit"
```